# Apache 2.2 rewrite with Alias only works in [R] mode

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I have a `mod_rewrite` rule to pass requests to a front controller, but I can't seem to get it working without an `[R]` flag.

The set-up isn't entirely straightforward, I have an aliased directory inside the web root, and I'm trying to rewrite into that directory. If I ignore that directory, I can get it to rewrite just fine.

If I use:

```
Alias /main /some/path/
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule /main/(.*)$ /main/index.php/$1 [R]
```

It works as expected, and index.php receives the value as a parameter, but since it's using the [R] flag, a request for `/main/some-param` ends up as a URI ending in `/main/index.php/some-param` and I'm aiming to have it transparent.

Without the `[R]`, the request results in a 404 and a log entry along the lines of `File does not exist: /mywebroot/main` which seems odd.

Is there anything about using an `Alias` here that's causing it or is it an error with the rule itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the `Alias` that's causing the problem - the rewritten version is assumed to be a path to an actual file, (either an absolute filesystem path or one relative to the `DocumentRoot`). If you add a `PT` flag, the `Alias` will get correctly applied.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks. I really should have noticed `[PT]` given how close it is to `[R]` in the RewriteRule docs, and it specifically mentions it helping with the use of `mod_alias` and `mod_rewrite`.